# how to get values from a graph in a dashboard in grafana V 2.0

Tags: python, grafana

i have a graph on a 'grafana' dashboard v2.0.

i want to get a value from this graph using an HTTP get (from python)

i have tried [API Documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/v2.0/reference/http_api/)  but it is very poor. nothing is there for getting a value from a graph

i can find at the documentation only how to get a dashboard (`GET /api/dashboards/db/:slug`) with a token provided.

how can i get graph values?

(like if my metric is something like `queue.prod.high.total_queues`)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get metric values querying Grafana but Graphite. In python you can use the `requests` library and the [Graphite URL API](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/url-api.html#the-url-api) and the [`format`](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/url-api.html#format) parameter.

For example:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://your.graphite.host.com/render?target=queue.prod.high.total_queues&format=json')
data = response.json()
```